# Vectors magnitude problem

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

Let $\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}$ be vectors with $|\vec{a}|=4,|\vec{b}|=12, |\vec{c}|=3  $. I have to prove that: $$\vec{a}+\vec{b}+\vec{c}\neq\vec{0}  $$ 
Any ideas about that.

Comment: Could you show your progress so far? Also, the title you have chosen for your question doesn't give much insight about the actual problem. You should try to give your question a better title. Also, big hint: Pythagoras´  Theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that $a+b+c=0$ *does* hold and we'll prove it by contradiction.  Then move one of the vectors to the other side, let's say $c$:

$$a+b=-c$$

Then square both sides.  The LHS is $$(a+b)\cdot (a+b) = |a|^2 + |b|^2+2a\cdot b = |a|^2+|b|^2+2|a||b|\cos(\theta) = 160+96\cos(\theta)$$

On the RHS, we get $$(-c)\cdot(-c) = |-c|^2 = |c|^2 = 9$$

Then we have $$160+96\cos(\theta) = 9 \\ \cos(\theta)=\frac{-151}{96} \lt -1$$

But $\cos(\theta)$ is never less than $-1$.  Contradiction.  Thus $a+b+c\ne 0$.

---

Edit: Instead of using the inner product we could use the triangle inequality.

So we have $a+b+c=0$.  This time lets move the $b$ to the other side.  We get $a+c=-b$.  Take the norm of both sides to get $|a+c|=|-b|=|b|$.  Then by the triangle inequality we have $|a+c|\le |a|+|c|=7$.  But $|a+c|=|b|=12\gt 7$.  Contradiction.  Thus $a+b+c\ne 0$.

Comment: thank you..is there another solution without the use of the inner product?

Comment: See my edit.$\ $